# Most efficient way to pass data from one pandas DataFrame to another

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to find a more efficient way of transferring information from one DataFrame to another by iterating rows. I have 2 DataFrames, one containing unique values called 'id' in a column and a value called 'region' in another column:

```
dfkey = DataFrame({'id':[1122,3344,3467,1289,7397,1209,5678,1792,1928,4262,9242],
            'region': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]})

      id  region
0   1122       1
1   3344       2
2   3467       3
3   1289       4
4   7397       5
5   1209       6
6   5678       7
7   1792       8
8   1928       9
9   4262      10
10  9242      11
```

...the other DataFrame contains these same ids, but now sometimes repeated and without any order:

```
df2 = DataFrame({'id':[1792,1122,3344,1122,3467,1289,7397,1209,5678],
            'other': [3,2,3,4,3,5,7,3,1]})

     id  other
0  1792      3
1  1122      2
2  3344      3
3  1122      4
4  3467      3
5  1289      5
6  7397      7
7  1209      3
8  5678      1
```

I want to use the dfkey DataFrame as a key to input the region of each id in the df2 DataFrame. I already found a way to do this with iterrows(), but it involves nested loops:

```
df2['region']=0
for i, rowk in dfkey.iterrows():
    for j, rowd in df2.iterrows():
        if rowk['id'] == rowd['id']: 
            rowd['region'] = rowk['region']

     id  other  region
0  1792      3       8
1  1122      2       1
2  3344      3       2
3  1122      4       1
4  3467      3       3
5  1289      5       4
6  7397      7       5
7  1209      3       6
8  5678      1       7
```

The actual dfkey I have has 43K rows and the df2 600K rows. The code has been running for an hour now so I'm wondering if there's a more efficient way of doing this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use [map()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) method:

```
In [268]: df2['region'] = df2['id'].map(dfkey.set_index('id').region)

In [269]: df2
Out[269]:
     id  other  region
0  1792      3       8
1  1122      2       1
2  3344      3       2
3  1122      4       1
4  3467      3       3
5  1289      5       4
6  7397      7       5
7  1209      3       6
8  5678      1       7
```

Timing for 900K rows `df2` DF:

```
In [272]: df2 = pd.concat([df2] * 10**5, ignore_index=True)

In [273]: df2.shape
Out[273]: (900000, 3)

In [274]: dfkey.shape
Out[274]: (11, 2)

In [275]: %timeit df2['id'].map(dfkey.set_index('id').region)
10 loops, best of 3: 176 ms per loop
```

Comment: Thanks again @MaxU! It worked really fast... its actually amazing how some methods are far more efficient than others

Answer (score 1):

`pandas.merge` could be another solution.

```
newdf = pandas.merge(df2, dfkey, on='id')

In [22]: newdf
Out[22]: 
     id  other  region
0  1792      3       8
1  1122      2       1
2  1122      4       1
3  3344      3       2
4  3467      3       3
5  1289      5       4
6  7397      7       5
7  1209      3       6
8  5678      1       7
```